# I can not debug a JavaEE application with Gradle, Dropwizard and IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I have a JavaEE application with Gradle which I added Dropwizard following the official documentation (for Maven) and another guide for Gradle:

https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/getting-started.html
https://karollotkowski.wordpress.com/2015/10/13/run-dropwizard-with-gradle/

The application is well configured and runs with Gradle and Dropwizard but I want to debug the application using break points and I am not be able to do it. I follow this guide:

https://medium.com/grandcentrix/how-to-debug-gradle-plugins-with-intellij-eef2ef681a7b

It looks ok because when I run the command:

> sudo ./gradlew run -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon

Gradle waits for I do click on the remote debug configuration (which I created it) in IntelliJ to run the application so it should be ok. However, it never stops in my break points (looks like it ignore them). Any idea?   I share the files which I consider important:

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

project.ext {
    dropwizardVersion = '1.3.0'
    configPath = "$rootProject.projectDir/config/"
}

//
// Loads of repositories and dependencies including dropwizard
//

protobuf {
// Configure the protoc executable
    protoc {
        // Download from repositories
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }

    generateProtoTasks.generatedFilesBaseDir = 'generated'

    generateProtoTasks {
        // all() returns the collection of all protoc tasks
        all().each { task ->
            // Here you can configure the task
        }

        // In addition to all(), you may get the task collection by various
        // criteria:

        // (Java only) returns tasks for a sourceSet
        ofSourceSet('main')

    }
}

mainClassName = "com.company.MyApplication"

run {
    args 'server', configPath + ‘myapplication_config.yml'
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

build.dependsOn shadowJar
```

**MyApplicationApplication (Dropwizard Application):**

```
public class MyApplicationApplication extends Application<MyApplicationConfiguration> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new MyApplicationApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(MyApplicationConfiguration configuration,
                    Environment environment) {

        environment.jersey().register(new RESTUserBilling());

    }
}
```

**MyApplicationConfiguration (Dropwizard Configuration):**

```
public class MyApplicationConfiguration extends Configuration {

}
```

**myapplication_config.yml:**

```
# Logging settings.
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: ERROR, DEBUG

  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:

    # Sets the level for 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
    com.company: DEBUG

  appenders:
  - type: console
  - type: file
    threshold: INFO
    logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
    currentLogFilename: /var/log/dropwizard/myapplication.log
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/dropwizard/myapplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
    archivedFileCount: 7
    timeZone: UTC
    maxFileSize: 10MB

server:
  applicationContextPath: /myapplication
  adminConnectors:
  -
    port: 8091
    type: http
  applicationConnectors:
  -
    port: 80
    type: http
```

**Remote configuration** in IntelliJ IntelliJ 2018.2.1 (Community Edition)

[image]

> Gradle 2.12
>
> Java version 1.8.0_181
>
> Dropwizard version 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` as in that article you're debugging Gradle's process and not the application you're working on. Gradle runs your application in a different process. You should try `gradle --debug-jvm run`. Read more about that [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#example_configure_the_application_main_class) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html#setDebug-boolean-)

And update Gradle, seriously. 2.12 is too old. Use [wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

If 2.12 does not understand `--debug-jvm` (which may be the case) then just find a  way to provide a string like this — `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` — to the JVM your app runs (not the Gradle itself).

Comment: Thanks, it works. Gradle 2.12 understand --debug-jvm. However, I will follow your advice and I will try to update Gradle.